# (Dual application) 2 Samuel 7:12-17 attributed to King David and his earthly descendants, & David's Heavenly & earthly descendant, Jesus Christ

Tags: sin, 2-samuel

> 2 Samuel 7:12-17 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>     12 When your days
>   are complete and you lie down with your fathers, I will raise up your
>   [c]descendant after you, who will come forth from [d]you, and I will
>   establish his kingdom. 13 He shall build a house for My name, and I
>   will establish the throne of his kingdom forever.14 I will be a
>   father to him and he will be a son to Me; when he commits iniquity, I
>   will correct him with the rod of men and the strokes of the sons of
>   men, 15 but My lovingkindness shall not depart from him, as I took it
>   away from Saul, whom I removed from before you. 16 Your house and your
>   kingdom shall endure before [e]Me forever; your throne shall be
>   established forever.”’” 17 In accordance with all these words and all
>   this vision, so Nathan spoke to David.

Would it be a correct to interpret 2 Samuel 7:12-17  in such a way that there is a dual application/nature since it can be implied as prophesying about King David and his descendants, and also King David's most famous descendant Jesus Christ, The Lord and Savior?

To Elaborate,

> 2 Samuel 7:12 I will raise up your [c]descendant after you, who will
>   come forth from [d]you, and I will establish his kingdom.

- 2 Samuel 7:12 can be interpreted as prophesying about King David, and
  his descendants "Earthly" Israelite kingdom   and can also be Jesus
  Christ as King of the Kingdom of Heaven

> 2 Samuel 7:13 He shall build a house for My name, and I will establish
>   the throne of his kingdom forever.

2 Samuel 7:13 can be interpreted as King David's son, King Solomon's construction of the Holy "Earthly" Solomon's Temple in Jerusalem
and can also be interpreted as Jesus Christ's body as a temple being built on resurrection day

> 2 Samuel 7:14 I will be a
>   father to him and he will be a son to Me; when he commits iniquity, I
>   will correct him with the rod of men and the strokes of the sons of
>   men,

2 Samuel 7:14 can obviously be interpreted as Kind David's son, King Solomon, being disciplined when he sins( in King Solomon's case his marriage to Non-Jewish women who led his away from the Lord of Israel), and also the sins of all the "earthly" Kings who were descended from King David
and 
when it comes to King David's descendant, Jesus Christ, we can the aforementioned verse as Jesus Christ being discipled for the inequities of all the sins of the believers of Jesus Christ because Jesus Christ took the blame for all sins of the believers of Jesus Christ

Would the aforementioned interpretations be correct?